# How to pass request headers in sencha touch for jsonp proxy type

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Hi i was trying to pass the request headers for jsonp proxy type request i was unabel to see the header params in request header in browser

Comment: Provide a code example of what you have done.  Code examples are important in stack overflow.

Comment: Thank for your reply actually i like to  pass header params from sencha tohch through jsonp proxy for this rest endd point 

public void put(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") MediaType contentType, ...)